# pod has unbound PersistentVolumeClaims

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-storage

When I push my deployments, for some reason, I'm getting the error on my pods:

> pod has unbound PersistentVolumeClaims

Here are my YAML below:

This is running locally, not on any cloud solution.

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.16.0 ()
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: ckan
  name: ckan
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: ckan
    spec:
      containers:
        image: slckan/docker_ckan
        name: ckan
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
            - name: ckan-home
              mountPath: /usr/lib/ckan/
              subPath: ckan
      volumes:
      - name: ckan-home
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: ckan-pv-home-claim
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

---

```yaml
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ckan-pv-home-claim
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: ckan
spec:
  storageClassName: ckan-home-sc
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ckan-home-sc
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0755
  - file_mode=0755
  - uid=1000
  - gid=1000
```

Answer (score 169, accepted):

You have to define a **PersistentVolume** providing disc space to be consumed by the **PersistentVolumeClaim**.

When using `storageClass` Kubernetes is going to enable **"Dynamic Volume Provisioning"** which is not working with the local file system.

---

#### To solve your issue:

- Provide a **PersistentVolume** fulfilling the constraints of the claim (a size >= 100Mi)
- Remove the `storageClass` from the **PersistentVolumeClaim** or provide it with an empty value (`""`)
- Remove the **StorageClass** from your cluster

---

#### How do these pieces play together?

At creation of the deployment state-description it is usually known which kind (amount, speed, ...) of storage that application will need.
To make a deployment versatile you'd like to avoid a hard dependency on storage. Kubernetes' volume-abstraction allows you to provide and consume storage in a standardized way.

The **PersistentVolumeClaim** is used to provide a storage-constraint alongside the deployment of an application.

The **PersistentVolume** offers cluster-wide volume-instances ready to be consumed ("`bound`"). One PersistentVolume will be bound to *one* claim. But since multiple instances of that claim may be run on multiple nodes, that volume may be [accessed](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) by multiple nodes.

A **PersistentVolume without StorageClass** is considered to be **static**.

[**"Dynamic Volume Provisioning"**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning) alongside **with** a **StorageClass** allows the cluster to provision PersistentVolumes on demand.
In order to make that work, the given storage provider must support [provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#provisioner) - this allows the cluster to request the provisioning of a "new" **PersistentVolume** when an unsatisfied **PersistentVolumeClaim** pops up.

---

#### Example PersistentVolume

In order to find how to specify things you're best advised to take a look at the [API for your Kubernetes version](https://kubernetes.io/de/docs/reference/#api-referenz), so the following example is build from the [API-Reference of K8S 1.17](https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#persistentvolume-v1-core):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: ckan-pv-home
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Mi
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data/ckan"
```

The **PersistentVolumeSpec** allows us to define multiple attributes.
I chose a `hostPath` volume which maps a local directory as content for the volume. The capacity allows the resource scheduler to recognize this volume as applicable in terms of resource needs.

---

#### Additional Resources:

- [Configure PersistentVolume Guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/)

Comment: You may not remove StorageClass, it is enough just replacing value of storage class name to an empty string, like StorageClass: ""

Comment: How should the PersistentVolume be defined?

Comment: @VictorZuanazzi good question - it seems the docs slightly changed, i added an example. Digging into the API is pretty hard at the beginning. Fortunatley there are often cross-references from the API-docs to the guides and vice versa. I hope this helps you to go on.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @mrvol - i added that option to the description.

Comment: Do you need to attach a PersistentVolume to a StatefulSet?

Comment: I guess it depends – i haven't used StatefulSets yet. When you're going to use a StatefulSet and your application meets requirements described here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#using-statefulsets then its likely you require a PersistentVolume. See the API here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.23/#statefulsetspec-v1-apps and think about filing a dedicated SO question if you need further help.

Comment: @FlorianNeumann The documents mentions its for a single node cluster. What if my cluster has more than 1 node?

Comment: @TheEsnSiavashi - i am not sure which docs you're referring to. But one claim can be used by multiple nodes depending on your deployment, kubernetes should take care of this unless you configure the PV to be consumed in a special way (see f.e. the ReadWriteOncePod: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes)

Answer (score 5):

If you ever see pod events like: `0/n nodes are available...pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims...Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.` you probably want to look next at what `PersistentVolumeClaim` is actually unbound.

Try `kubectl get pvc` and you may see something like:

```
% kubectl get pvc
NAME               STATUS     VOLUME       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
unbound-volume     Pending                                                                        nfs            8m25s
good-volume        Bound      pvc-exists   1Gi        RWO            gp2            20h
```

You'll likely see the pvc you're looking for in the `Pending` status (in our example `unbound-volume`), but it could be stuck in some other status. Right now our persistent volume claim only has a *claim* to a volume, which it's currently waiting for - and until it gets that volume your pod won't start.

We can take a closer look with `kubectl describe pvc`, where we should see a more helpful message describing the volume provisioning issue in detail:

```
% kubectl describe pvc unbound-volume 
...
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age                   From                         Message
  ----    ------                ----                  ----                         -------
  Normal  ExternalProvisioning  3m30s (x42 over 13m)  persistentvolume-controller  waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "cluster.local/bad-nfs-provisioner" or manually created by system administrator
```

In my case I was running an nfs provisioner that was failing to create new nfs volumes. In your case, whatever is supposed to be provisioning your cluster's `persistentvolumes` for that volume's storage class may be faltering, or maybe it's the wrong `storageclass` as other posts mention.

Answer (score 4):

If your using rancher k3s kubernetes distribution, set `storageClassName` to `local-path` as described in the [doc](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/storage/#:%7E:text=K3s%20comes%20with%20Rancher%E2%80%99s%20Local%20Path%20Provisioner%20and%20this%20enables%20the%20ability%20to%20create%20persistent%20volume%20claims%20out%20of%20the%20box%20using%20local%20storage%20on%20the%20respective%20node.%20Below%20we%20cover%20a%20simple%20example.%20For%20more%20information%20please%20reference%20the%20official%20documentation%20here.)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: local-path-pvc
  namespace: default
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: local-path
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

To use it on other distributions use https://github.com/rancher/local-path-provisioner

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue but I realized that I was creating my PV's with "manual" StorageClass type.

YOUR POD
Expects what kind of storage class?

YOUR PVC Definition
volumeClaimTemplates --> storageClassName : "standard"

PV
spec --> storageClassName : "standard"

Answer (score 1):

We faced a very similar issue today.  For us the problem was that there was no CSI driver installed on the nodes. To check the drivers installed, you can use this command:

```
kubectl get csidriver
```

Our managed kubernetes clusters v1.25 run in Google Cloud, so for us the solution was to just enable the feature ‘Compute Engine persistent disk CSI Driver’

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In may case the problem was, the wrong name of `PersistentVolume` specified in `PersistentVolumeClaim` declaration.

But there might be more reasons to it. Make sure that :

1. The `volumeName` name specified in `PVC` match `PV` name
2. The `storageClassName` name specified in `PVC` match `PV` name
3. The sufficient capacity size is allocated to your resource
4. The access modes of You `PV` and `PVC` are consistent
5. The number of `PV` match `PVC`

For detailed explanation read this [article](https://www.datree.io/resources/kubernetes-troubleshooting-fixing-persistentvolumeclaims-error).