# How to fix 'pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims' in SQL 2019 Big Data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I want to set up simple persistent storage on Kubernetes for SQL 2019 Big Data on prem. But keeps throwing an event 'pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims'.

When I deploy the image, pod mssql-controller shows an event:

```
Name:               mssql-controller-6vd8b
Namespace:          sql2019
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               <none>
Labels:             MSSQL_CLUSTER=sql2019
                    app=mssql-controller
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Pending
IP:
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/mssql-controller
Containers:
  mssql-controller:
    Image:      private-repo.microsoft.com/mssql-private-preview/mssql-controller:latest
    Port:       8081/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA:                  Y
      CONTROLLER_ENABLE_TDS_PROXY:  false
      KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE:         sql2019 (v1:metadata.namespace)
    Mounts:
      /root/secrets/controller-db from controller-db-secret (ro)
      /root/secrets/controller-login from controller-login-secret (ro)
      /root/secrets/knox from controller-knox-secret (ro)
      /root/secrets/node-admin-login from node-admin-login-secret (ro)
      /var/opt from controller-storage (rw)
      /var/opt/controller/config from controller-config-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from sa-mssql-controller-token-4fsbc (ro)
  mssql-portal:
    Image:        private-repo.microsoft.com/mssql-private-preview/mssql-portal:latest
    Port:         6001/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/opt from controller-storage (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from sa-mssql-controller-token-4fsbc (ro)
  mssql-server-controller:
    Image:      private-repo.microsoft.com/mssql-private-preview/mssql-server-controller:latest
    Port:       1433/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA:  Y
      SA_PASSWORD:  <password removed>
    Mounts:
      /var/opt from controller-storage (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from sa-mssql-controller-token-4fsbc (ro)
  mssql-monitor-fluentbit:
    Image:      private-repo.microsoft.com/mssql-private-preview/mssql-monitor-fluentbit:latest
    Port:       2020/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Limits:
      memory:  100Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  100Mi
    Environment:
      FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:  service-monitor-elasticsearch
      FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT:  9200
      FLUENTBIT_CONFIG:           fluentbit-controller.conf
      KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE:       sql2019 (v1:metadata.namespace)
      KUBERNETES_NODE_NAME:        (v1:spec.nodeName)
      KUBERNETES_POD_NAME:        mssql-controller-6vd8b (v1:metadata.name)
    Mounts:
      /var/opt from controller-storage (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from sa-mssql-controller-token-4fsbc (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False
Volumes:
  controller-storage:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  mssql-controller-pvc
    ReadOnly:   false
  controller-login-secret:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  controller-login-secret
    Optional:    false
  controller-db-secret:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  controller-db-secret
    Optional:    false
  controller-knox-secret:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  controller-knox-secret
    Optional:    false
  node-admin-login-secret:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  node-admin-login-secret
    Optional:    false
  controller-config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      mssql-controller-config
    Optional:  false
  sa-mssql-controller-token-4fsbc:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  sa-mssql-controller-token-4fsbc
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age              From               Message
  ----     ------            ----             ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  1s (x6 over 4s)  default-scheduler  pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
```

Cluster config:

```
export USE_PERSISTENT_VOLUME=true
export STORAGE_CLASS_NAME=slow
```

StorageClass.yaml

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: slow
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
  replication-type: none
```

I'm quite new to Kubernetes, but these are the things I know:

- I need Dynamic Volume Provisioning
- I need to create Storage Class (SQL 2019 creates Persistent Volume and Persistent Volume Claim)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pod has unbound PersistentVolumeClaims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668938/pod-has-unbound-persistentvolumeclaims)?

Comment: I have tried to folow this solution but did not work. I think I do fulfill constraints of the claim because its part of the deployment of the SQL 2019. 2nd and 3rd options are not viable because as far as I understand I do need dynamic volume provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it occured while using minikube. I believe it can occur even on any cloud provider.

The reason for this is because one or more PVCs may have their storage specification request more disk space than is available.

Check your

```
...
resources:
  requests:
    storage: <value must be <= than available space>
```

I hope this helps someone.