# Getting "CrashLoopBackOff" as status of deployed pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

How to debug why it's status is CrashLoopBackOff?

I am not using minikube , working on Aws Kubernetes instance.

I followed this tutorial.
https://github.com/mkjelland/spring-boot-postgres-on-k8s-sample

When I do

```
  kubectl create -f specs/spring-boot-app.yml
```

and check status by

```
  kubectl get pods
```

it gives

```
     spring-boot-postgres-sample-67f9cbc8c-qnkzg   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   14         50m
```

Below Command

```
 kubectl describe pods spring-boot-postgres-sample-67f9cbc8c-qnkzg
```

gives

```
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                    From                      Message
  ----     ------   ----                   ----                      -------
  Warning  BackOff  3m18s (x350 over 78m)  kubelet, ip-172-31-11-87  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Command **kubectl get pods --all-namespaces** gives

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                           READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
default       constraintpod                                  1/1     Running            1          88d
default       postgres-78f78bfbfc-72bgf                      1/1     Running            0          109m
default       rcsise-krbxg                                   1/1     Running            1          87d
default       spring-boot-postgres-sample-667f87cf4c-858rx   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   4          110s
default       twocontainers                                  2/2     Running            479        89d
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-kr4zj                       1/1     Running            1          89d
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-qqq2p                       1/1     Running            1          89d
kube-system   etcd-ip-172-31-6-149                           1/1     Running            8          89d
kube-system   kube-apiserver-ip-172-31-6-149                 1/1     Running            1          89d
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-ip-172-31-6-149        1/1     Running            1          89d
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-4h4x7                    1/1     Running            1          89d
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-fcvf2                    1/1     Running            1          89d
kube-system   kube-proxy-5sgjb                               1/1     Running            1          89d
kube-system   kube-proxy-hd7tr                               1/1     Running            1          89d
kube-system   kube-scheduler-ip-172-31-6-149                 1/1     Running            1          89d
```

Command **kubectl logs spring-boot-postgres-sample-667f87cf4c-858rx**
doesn't print anything.

Comment: you can check pods using `kubectl describe pods spring-boot-postgres-sample-67f9cbc8c-qnkzg`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Edited ..i added Events :., anything else you want me to add?

Comment: `docker logs container_id` to show logs of container belong to that pods

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to get container_id...I tried **kubectl logs <dockerhubaccount_username>/jarName** but no such container

Comment: Run `kubectl describe pods spring-boot-postgres-sample-67f9cbc8c-qnkzg` it show container belong to.

Comment: It gives under container section : - **Container ID:   docker://c9704202d90fbfa87274d59dd571d2084de2b969db2be20aaffe5f0801b5f52d**

Comment: `docker logs c9704202d90fbfa87274d59dd571d2084de2b969db2be20aaffe5f0801b5f52d`

Comment: I did **sudo docker logs c9704202d90fbfa87274d59dd571d2084de2b969db2be20aaffe5f0801b5f52d** but it gives no such container_id

Comment: run `kubectl describe pods` again. get new container_id then show its logs

Comment: Again same error

Comment: Please run same docker image with docker ex. docker run and see

Comment: Sorry,I didn't understood ..can you give me exact command?

Comment: are you able to run the docker image on your local machine? maybe you forgot to change the image name in the yml file?

Comment: can you run this command and show the output: kubectl get pods --all-namespaces 

and kubectl logs spring-boot-postgres-sample-67f9cbc8c-qnkzg to get the logs of pod

Comment: @AnshulJindal added to question

Comment: Have you tried running this application locally without Kubernetes ?

Comment: I build it on my window machine,then put that jar in kubernetes instance..and from there to created image to docker

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan, I need you thoughts on my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I fixed by postgres deployment, there was some error of "pod has unbound PersistentVolumeClaims" , so i fixed that error by this post 
[pod has unbound PersistentVolumeClaims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668938/pod-has-unbound-persistentvolumeclaims)

So now my postgres deployment is running.

**kubectl logs spring-boot-postgres-sample-67f9cbc8c-qnkzg** doesn't print anything, it means there is something wrong in config file.
**kubectl describe pod spring-boot-postgres-sample-67f9cbc8c-qnkzg** stating that container is terminated and reason is completed,
I fixed it by running container infinity time
by adding

```
   # Just sleep forever
command: [ "sleep" ]
args: [ "infinity" ]
```

So now my deployment is running.
But now i Exposed my service by

```
kubectl expose deployment spring-boot-postgres-sample --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080
```

but can't able to get External-Ip , so I did

```
kubectl patch svc <svc-name> -n <namespace> -p '{"spec": {"type": "LoadBalancer", "externalIPs":["172.31.71.218"]}}'
```

So I get my external-Ip as "172.31.71.218"

But now the problem is curl http://172.31.71.218:8080/ getting timeout

Anything i did wrong?

Here is my deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: spring-boot-postgres-sample
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: spring-boot-postgres-sample
      labels:
        app: spring-boot-postgres-sample
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: spring-boot-postgres-sample
        command: [ "/bin/bash", "-ce", "tail -f /dev/null" ]
        env:
          - name: POSTGRES_USER
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: postgres-config
                key: postgres_user
          - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: postgres-config
                key: postgres_password
          - name: POSTGRES_HOST
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: hostname-config
                key: postgres_host
        image: <mydockerHUbaccount>/spring-boot-postgres-on-k8s:v1
```

Here is my postgres.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-config
  namespace: default
data:
  postgres_user: postgresuser
  postgres_password: password
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
      containers:
        - image: postgres
          name: postgres
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-config
                  key: postgres_user
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-config
                  key: postgres_password
            - name: PGDATA
              value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
              name: postgres
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgres-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 5432
  selector:
    app: postgres
```

Here How i got host-config map

```
kubectl create configmap hostname-config --from-literal=postgres_host=$(kubectl get svc postgres -o jsonpath="{.spec.clusterIP}")
```

Comment: Can't able to get logs..does it mean still my config is wrong?can you please check my deployment.yaml.. @ThanhNguyenVan

Comment: did you create `postgres` and `configmap` ?

Comment: Yes . I did ... I also added my postgres.config and host-config

Comment: Both services status is running

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you...

1. run a dummy container (run an endless sleep command)
2. kubectl exec -it  bash
3. Run the program directly and have a look at the logs directly.

Its an easier form of debugging on K8s.

Comment: I have spring boot jar, what do you mean by run program directly..and how to look at their logs?

Comment: Does this not show you the output?

```bash
kubectl logs <container-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the scenario. Seems there is a connectivity issue between the app and Postgres DB. So the app failed to initiate. Please find the logs below it might help you.

```
$ kubectl get po
NAME                                           READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
spring-boot-postgres-sample-5d7c85d98b-qwvjr   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   19         1h


org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

2019-05-23 10:53:01.889 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to :5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:262) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
```

Comment: `kubectl logs spring-boot-postgres-sample-5d7c85d98b-hl5z2 -f`

Comment: Why it's not printing something in my case?