# Deploying Cassandra on kubernetes cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, cassandra

I have been trying to deploy Cassandra using following documentation 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/cassandra/

deployment of Cassandra works fine but when i try to create statefull set it gives following error :

> Cassandra 0 
>   pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 2 times)

can any one help me where am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Compare with similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668938/pod-has-unbound-persistentvolumeclaims

Comment: Did you ever manage to deploy Cassandra on docker or AWS EKS?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create correct [storage class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#azure-disk) and named it `fast`?

Try with this one (should work on azure):

```
...
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: cassandra-data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: fast
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi

---
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: fast
parameters:
  fsType: xfs
  kind: Managed
  storageaccounttype: Premium_LRS
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-disk
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

Comment: I used a followed your advice and created the fast StorageClass, to no avail:          Warning  FailedScheduling  11s (x3 over 81s)  default-scheduler  error while running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "cassandra-0": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. I think it is a RBAC security issue but I dont know how to debug it

Comment: What is your cloud provider?

Comment: EKS on AWS       (by the way I just managed to use helm incubator chart with helm 2). kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace kube-system tiller
kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller

Comment: I do not recommend helm 2 for security reasons - you just gave tiller full access to your cluster, check if you could install it with helm3.

Comment: Good point, For now it is a POC and I had trouble with Helm 3 on Mac so it will do for now. Do you have an answer to the Plain yaml statefulset conundrum? I'm sure it's some kind of rolebinding mess

Comment: Take your time and make use of helm3, I am using it on mac and it works great - installed via brew.

Comment: `Do you have an answer to the Plain yaml statefulset conundrum?` sorry, can you explain I don't get it?

Comment: Why does the yaml example in the question not work on EKS or docker with the respective storage class modified to the specific kubernetes deployment. I suspect rbac security nonsense

Comment: As you can see above in my example I have `provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-disk`, every cloud provider has its own `provisioner` and this is why you cannot run it on aws.

Comment: on docker for descktop  provisioner: docker.io/hostpath on aws provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs don't work

Answer (score 0):

A stateful set requires a persistent volume where store the state, the docs you provide there is a section that shows it:

```
 volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: cassandra-data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: fast
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: fast
provisioner: k8s.io/minikube-hostpath
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd
```

these are the docs to create a PV and/or Storage class in Azure as you need

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv

then you can associate the object with your StatefulSet