# Elasticsearch statefulset replica not able to claim persistent volume data

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy Elasticsearch on Google kubernetes engine with 2 replicaset , so I have prepared deployment file , pv and service manifest files ,the first pod is running properly but second pod get stuck in pending state , after checking the pods description I got this message **0/2 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims** after that I checked pvc and got the **Reason FailedBinding:Messagevolume "elasticsearch-pv" already bound to a different claim.**

My doubt is why it is happening  because in my statefulset I have defined volumeClaimTemplates and requesting 3gb out of 10gb of pv , how can I resolved this issue.

My persistent volume yaml file :-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
 name: elasticsearch-pv
 namespace: elk
spec:
 capacity:
   storage: 10Gi
 accessModes:
 - ReadWriteOnce
 nfs:
   path: /filestore_vol1/elastic-gke/
   server: 10.x.x.122
```

My statefulset yaml file :-

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-cluster
  namespace: elk
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: app-elk
                operator: In
                values:
                - "elastic-tomcat"
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: elasticsearch:7.17.5
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
            requests:
              cpu: 200m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: rest
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: inter-node
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        env:
          - name: cluster.name
            value: elasticsearch-cluster
          - name: node.name
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: discovery.seed_hosts
            value: "elasticsearch-cluster-0.elasticsearch,elasticsearch-cluster-1.elasticsearch"
          - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
            value: "elasticsearch-cluster-0"
          - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
            value: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
          - name: network.host
            value: "0.0.0.0"
      initContainers:
      - name: fix-permissions
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - name: increase-vm-max-map
        image: busybox
        command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      - name: increase-fd-ulimit
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: ""
      volumeName: elasticsearch-pv
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 3Gi
```

Error screenshots:-

[image: pods details]

[image: issue on 2nd pod]

[image: pvc issue]

Answer (score 0):

Since you have explicitly put a `volumeName:` in the PVC template definition, every PersistentVolumeClaim attempts to bind to the same PersistentVolume.  A PersistentVolume may only be bound to a single PersistentVolumeClaim (see for example the [Binding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#binding) section of the Kubernetes Persistent Volumes documentation) and so the second replica will get the error you report.

In normal use you shouldn't need to manually create PersistentVolumes.  The cluster persistent-volume provisioner will manage this for you.  Delete the manually-created PV and the `volumeName:` line from the template, and the cluster will create a new PV for each StatefulSet replica.

Comment: Hi , for storage we have a filestore NFS , I need to use that for mounting to the pod thats why I have created a pv which contains the filestore mount point also Since each Elasticsearch pods has its own data folder, I need to have separate data folder for each replica in the PV (filestore).

Comment: Each StatefulSet replica will create a new PersistentVolumeClaim, and each PVC needs a different PersistentVolume.

Comment: I already have a filestore of 1Tb why would I want to provision another persistent volume , I want to use it only I dont want to provsion any other disk , I need to store all my replica data on that filestore only.