# How to run Dgraph on bare-metal Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubectl, bare-metal, dgraph

I am trying to setup Dgraph in [HA Cluster](https://dgraph.io/docs/deploy/kubernetes/#ha-cluster-setup-using-kubernetes) but it won't deploy if no [volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) are present.

When directly applying [the provided config](https://github.com/dgraph-io/dgraph/blob/master/contrib/config/kubernetes/dgraph-ha/dgraph-ha.yaml) on a bare-metal cluster won't work.

```
$ kubectl get pod --namespace dgraph
dgraph-alpha-0                      0/1     Pending     0          112s
dgraph-ratel-7459974489-ggnql       1/1     Running     0          112s
dgraph-zero-0                       0/1     Pending     0          112s


$ kubectl describe pod/dgraph-alpha-0 --namespace dgraph
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age        From               Message
  ----     ------            ----       ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  error while running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "dgraph-alpha-0": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
  Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  error while running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "dgraph-alpha-0": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
```

Anyone else has this problem? I've been experiencing this issue for several days now and can not find a way around this.
How can I have Dgraph use cluster's local storage?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a definition of a PersistentVolume in the yaml you linked above, this needs to exist in order to fulfill the claim

Comment: the yaml uses the storage class to create the PersistentVolume you can test the yaml out on a cluster that has storageclass setup and you will see the pv created..it is a problem here because am on bare metall k8s cluster and do not have a way to make storageclass work

Comment: If you have a storage class, this will solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52669115/1970639

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a working solution myself.

I have to manually create the [`pv`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) and [`pvc`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/), then Dgraph can use them during deployment.

Here is the config I used to create the needed `storageclass`, `pv` and `pvc`

```
---
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: datadir-dgraph-dgraph-alpha-0
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: local
  capacity:
    storage: 8Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/dgraph/alpha-0"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: datadir-dgraph-dgraph-alpha-1
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: local
  capacity:
    storage: 8Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/dgraph/alpha-1"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: datadir-dgraph-dgraph-alpha-2
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: local
  capacity:
    storage: 8Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/dgraph/alpha-2"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: datadir-dgraph-dgraph-zero-0
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: local
  capacity:
    storage: 8Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/dgraph/zero-0"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: datadir-dgraph-dgraph-zero-1
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: local
  capacity:
    storage: 8Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/dgraph/zero-1"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: datadir-dgraph-dgraph-zero-2
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: local
  capacity:
    storage: 8Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/dgraph/zero-2"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: datadir-dgraph-dgraph-alpha-0
spec:
  storageClassName: local
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: datadir-dgraph-dgraph-alpha-1
spec:
  storageClassName: local
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: datadir-dgraph-dgraph-alpha-2
spec:
  storageClassName: local
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: datadir-dgraph-dgraph-zero-0
spec:
  storageClassName: local
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: datadir-dgraph-dgraph-zero-1
spec:
  storageClassName: local
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: datadir-dgraph-dgraph-zero-2
spec:
  storageClassName: local
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
```

When Dgraph is deployed it latches at the `pvc`

```
$ kubectl get pvc -n dgraph -o wide
NAME                            STATUS   VOLUME                          CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE     VOLUMEMODE
datadir-dgraph-dgraph-alpha-0   Bound    datadir-dgraph-dgraph-zero-2    8Gi        RWO            local          6h40m   Filesystem
datadir-dgraph-dgraph-alpha-1   Bound    datadir-dgraph-dgraph-alpha-0   8Gi        RWO            local          6h40m   Filesystem
datadir-dgraph-dgraph-alpha-2   Bound    datadir-dgraph-dgraph-zero-0    8Gi        RWO            local          6h40m   Filesystem
datadir-dgraph-dgraph-zero-0    Bound    datadir-dgraph-dgraph-alpha-1   8Gi        RWO            local          6h40m   Filesystem
datadir-dgraph-dgraph-zero-1    Bound    datadir-dgraph-dgraph-alpha-2   8Gi        RWO            local          6h40m   Filesystem
datadir-dgraph-dgraph-zero-2    Bound    datadir-dgraph-dgraph-zero-1    8Gi        RWO            local          6h40m   Filesystem
```

Answer (score 0):

Dgraph's configs assume a Kubernetes cluster with a working volume plugin (provisioner). In managed Kubernetes offerings (aws, GKE, DO etc) this step is already taken care by the provider.

I think the goal should be to achieve par functionality with cloud providers, that is the provisioning must be dynamic (in contrast for example with OP's own answer which is correct but [statically provisioned](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#static) - k8s docs).

When running bare-metal you have to manually configure a volume plugin before being able to [dynamically provision volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/) (k8s docs) and thus use StatefulSets, PersistentVolumeClaims etc. Thankfully there are [many provisioners available](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#provisioner) (k8s docs). *For **out of the box** support for dynamic provisioning every item in the list that has 'Internal Provisioner' checked will do.*

So while the problem has many solutions I ended up using NFS. To achieve dynamic provisioning I had to use an external provisioner. Hopefully this is as simple as installing a [Helm Chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nfs-client-provisioner).

1. [Install NFS](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-nfs-client-and-server-on-ubuntu-2004/) (original guide) on master node.

ssh via terminal and run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nfs-kernel-server nfs-common
```

2. Create the directory Kubernetes is going to use and change ownership

```
sudo mkdir /var/nfs/kubernetes -p
sudo chown nobody:nogroup /var/nfs/kubernetes
```

3. Configure NFS

Open the file `/etc/exports`

```
sudo nano /etc/exports
```

Add the following line at the bottom

```
/var/nfs/kubernetes  client_ip(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

**Replace** `client_ip` with you master node ip.
In my case this IP was the DHCP server IP leased by my router to the machine running master node (192.168.1.7)

4. Restart NFS to apply the changes.

```
sudo systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server
```

5. After setting up NFS on master and assuming Helm is present, installing the provisioner is as simple as running

```
helm install  nfs-provisioner --set nfs.server=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX --set nfs.path=/var/nfs/kubernetes --set storageClass.defaultClass=true stable/nfs-client-provisioner
```

**Replace** `nfs.server` flag with the appropriate IP/hostname of master node/NFS server.

Note flag `storageClass.defaultClass` has to be `true` in order for  Kubernetes to default use the plugin (provisioner) for volume creation.

Flag `nfs.path` is the same path as the one created in step 2.

In case Helm complains that [can not find the chart](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5434) run `helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/`

6. After successfully completing previous steps proceed installing Dgraph configs as [described in their docs](https://dgraph.io/docs/deploy/kubernetes/) and enjoy you bare-metal dynamically provisioned cluster with out-of-the-box working Dgraph deployment.

Single server

```
kubectl create --filename https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dgraph-io/dgraph/master/contrib/config/kubernetes/dgraph-single/dgraph-single.yaml
```

HA Cluster

```
kubectl create --filename https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dgraph-io/dgraph/master/contrib/config/kubernetes/dgraph-ha/dgraph-ha.yaml
```