# 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims - Kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, persistent-storage, persistent-volumes

I am trying to set `PersistentVolumeClaims` to my pods. Now the problem is when the `deployment` is success, the pods are in `pending` state. When I try to describe the pods, I get the error why they are not spinning up as below:

> Warning  FailedScheduling  20s (x3 over 22s)  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master: }, that the pod didn't tolerate, 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.

This is the `yaml` for creating the persistent volume and refer it in the deployments

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
    name: my-pvc
    namespace: mongo  
spec:
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
    resources:
        requests:
            storage: 2Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb-deployment
  namespace: mongo  
  labels:
    name: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo
        ports:
        -  containerPort: 27017
        env: 
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-username
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-password
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data  
          mountPath: /data/db
      volumes: 
        - name: data
          persistentVolumeClaim: 
            claimName: my-pvc    
                                  
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-express
  namespace: mongo  
  labels:
    app: mongo-express
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-express
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-express
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongo-express
        image: mongo-express
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
        env:
        - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-url
              key: database_url
        - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-username
        - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-password
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data  
          mountPath: /data
      volumes: 
        - name: data
          persistentVolumeClaim: 
            claimName: my-pvc    
---
.
.
.
```

I have removed the other yaml configurations from the above and keep the necessary ones only for easy-reading.

and when I try to see the status of the pvc using `kubectl get pvc -n mongo` I get the below `pending` status

> my-pvc   Pending                                                     9m54s

Can someone tell me where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

As described in [answer to pod has unbound PersistentVolumeClaims](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52669115/213269), if you use a `PersistentVolumeClaim` you typically need a *volume provisioner* for Dynamic Volume Provisioning. The bigger cloud providers typically has this, and also Minikube has one that can be enabled.

Unless you have a *volume provisioner* in your cluster, you need to create a [PersistentVolume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) resource and possibly also a StorageClass and declare how to use your storage system.

[Configure a Pod to Use a PersistentVolume for Storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/) describes how to create a `PersistentVolume` with a `hostPath` that may be good for learning or development, but is typically not used in production by applications.