# deploying Portainer on Kubernetes Cluster failed

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-18.04, portainer, kubernetes-cluster

after deploying Portainer on Kubernetes Cluster (1 master, 2 workers), following https://documentation.portainer.io/v2.0/deploy/ceinstallk8s/, by

```
helm install --create-namespace -n portainer portainer portainer/portainer --set persistence.storageClass=slow
```

I got the status:

```
kubectl get all -n portainer
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/portainer-6cb48f955f-qmtdq   0/1     Pending   0          2d
```

```
NAME                TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                          AGE
service/portainer   NodePort   10.97.158.200   <none>       9000:30777/TCP,30776:30776/TCP   2d3h
```

```
NAME                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/portainer   0/1     1            0           2d
```

```
NAME                                   DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/portainer-6cb48f955f   1         1         0       2d
```

So,
The pod is not READY, with STATUS Pending.
The service is up but has no EXTERNAL-IP.
The deployment is not READY or AVAILABLE.
The ReplicaSet is not READY.

And I can't access the instance on port 30777.
i.e. http://20.199.64.113:30777/

More 'kubectl describe' info:

```
root@kubemaster:/home/kubemaster# kubectl describe pod portainer -n portainer
Name:           portainer-7b94d88f67-plz9d
Namespace:      portainer
Priority:       0
Node:           <none>

Events:
Type     Reason            Age   From               Message
----     ------            ----  ----               -------
    Warning  FailedScheduling  129m  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 3 pod has unbound immediate Persiste

root@kubemaster:/home/kubemaster# kubectl describe pvc portainer -n portainer
Name:          portainer
Namespace:     portainer
StorageClass:  slow
Status:        Pending

Events:
    Type     Reason              Age                   From                         Message
    ----     ------              ----                  ----                         -------
    Warning  ProvisioningFailed  2m22s (x259 over 9h)  persistentvolume-controller  Failed to provision volume with S
```

```
root@kubemaster:/home/kubemaster# kubectl describe pv portainer -n portainer
Error from server (NotFound): persistentvolumes "portainer" not found
```

I did researched the below error/warning:

```
Warning  FailedScheduling  129m  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 3 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.


Warning  ProvisioningFailed  2m22s (x259 over 9h)  persistentvolume-controller  Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "slow": AzureDisk -  failed to get Azure Cloud Provider. GetCloudProvider returned <nil> instead
```

But still wasn't able to enable Portainer instance.

Is there anything i missed out or anyway to debug

thanks ahead

Comment: Can you properly edit your post - make commands more visible ? Please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64341805/2-pod-has-unbound-immediate-persistentvolumeclaims-kubernetes

Comment: Did you take a look on link I have provided ?

Comment: Yes, it's helpful. And redeployed K8s and installed https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner later on to make it work.
Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `PersistentVolumeClaim` you need a *volume provisioner* for [Dynamic Volume Provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/). The bigger cloud providers typically has this.

If you don't have a *volume provisioner* in your cluster, you have to create a [PersistentVolume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) resource and possibly also a StorageClass and declare how to use your storage system.

Take a look: [portainer-on-kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66560718/deploying-portainer-on-kubernetes-cluster-failed?noredirect=1#comment117860434_66560718).
So in your case as you have mentioned you can install external volume provisioner - [NFS subdir external provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner).