# How can I properly provision a volume for argo?

Tags: persistent-volume-claims, argo-workflows

I have a persistent volume running in the correct namespace:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: raw-data
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  hostPath: 
    path: /data
  storageClassName: storage
```

and would like to run a workflow that contains a volume claim template:

```
...
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: raw-data
    spec:
      accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 2Gi
```

I believe my configuration is consistent with that described here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52669115/213269 However, there are some differences since I am working on argo not kubernetes. I am receiving the following error:

```
 Unschedulable: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.
```

Question: How do I properly provision the volume?

UPDATE:

I have tried deploying a persistent volume into the argo namespace and pointing to it from the workflow and am now getting the following error:

```
persistentvolumeclaims "workflow-name" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:argo:argo" cannot get resource "persistentvolumeclaims" in API group "" in the namespace "argo"
```

I have also added a new user and context to the Kubernetes configuration to no avail.

UPDATE:

I added the following role and now the error has changed from "...User cannot get resource..." to "User cannot create resource..."  Note that my user does have permission to create persistentvolumeclaims.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1                                                                                                                                                                         kind: Role                                                                                                                                                                                                       metadata:                                                                                                                                                                                                          name: workflow                                                                                                                                                                                                   namespace: argo                                                                                                                                                                                                rules:                                                                                                                                                                                                           - apiGroups:                                                                                                                                                                                                       - ""                                                                                                                                                                                                             resources:                                                                                                                                                                                                       - pods                                                                                                                                                                                                           verbs:                                                                                                                                                                                                           - get                                                                                                                                                                                                            - list                                                                                                                                                                                                           - watch                                                                                                                                                                                                          - create                                                                                                                                                                                                         - update                                                                                                                                                                                                         - patch                                                                                                                                                                                                          - delete                                                                                                                                                                                                       - apiGroups:                                                                                                                                                                                                       - ""                                                                                                                                                                                                             resources:                                                                                                                                                                                                       - pods/log                                                                                                                                                                                                       verbs:                                                                                                                                                                                                           - get                                                                                                                                                                                                            - list                                                                                                                                                                                                           - watch                                                                                                                                                                                                          - create                                                                                                                                                                                                         - update                                                                                                                                                                                                         - patch                                                                                                                                                                                                          - delete                                                                                                                                                                                                       - apiGroups:                                                                                                                                                                                                       - ""                                                                                                                                                                                                             resources:                                                                                                                                                                                                        - persistentvolumeclaims                                                                                                                                                                                        verbs:                                                                                                                                                                                                           - get                                                                                                                                                                                                            - list                                                                                                                                                                                                           - watch                                                                                                                                                                                                          - create                                                                                                                                                                                                         - update                                                                                                                                                                                                         - patch                                                                                                                                                                                                          - delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an RBAC problem. Make sure the service account you're submitting your workflow with has read access to volumes.

Comment: I created the following role and now the error message is that I cannot create the resource (as versus "get" previously).  Note that the role does have permission to "create."  I am still getting it wrong :(

Comment: Thank you for your response!  You are correct that it appears to be an RBAC problem, so I am accepting this answer and creating a new question.  I tried to detail the persistent issues above, but they do not show up.