# How can I provision a volume (part II)?

Tags: kubernetes, volume, persistent-volume-claims

I am trying to configure RBAC so that I can provision a volume.  This is a follow-up of this ([How can I properly provision a volume for argo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64759440/how-can-i-properly-provision-a-volume-for-argo)) thread.  Adding a role changed the error from  "cannot **get** resource" to "cannot **create** resource".

I now think it is a Kubernetes issue, but still do not understand how to solve it.

error:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "/tmp/manifest.yaml": persistentvolumeclaims is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:argo:argo" cannot create resource "persistentvolumeclaims" in API group "" in the namespace "argo"
```

role.yaml

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: workflow
  namespace: argo
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
  - create
  - update
  - patch
  - delete
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods/log
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
  - create
  - update
  - patch
  - delete
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
   - persistentvolumeclaims
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
  - create
  - update
  - patch
  - delete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RBAC auth rules are configured with K8s resources which can be placed in two groups:

- `Roles` and `ClusterRole` which specify which verbs/actions can be
  performed on which resources.
- `RoleBindings` and `ClusterRoleBindings` which bind the above roles to
  specific users, groups or ServiceAccounts.

In your case you successfully created `Roles` but what you are missing is the `RoleBindings` so in short words who can perform the actions that you already specified.

Role binding can be created using yaml files:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: workflow-argo
  namespace: argo
subjects:
# You can specify more than one "subject"
- kind: User
  name: jane # "name" is case sensitive
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  # with "roleRef" you specify the binding to a Role / ClusterRole
  kind: Role 
  name: workflow # here you have to reference the name of your Role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

or with a command:

```
kubectl create rolebinding workflow-argo --clusterrole=workflow --user=jane --namespace=argo
```

For more check K8s section: [Using RBAC Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)