# GKE Can’t scale up nodes due of PersistentVolume

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm getting a strange problem on my Terraformed GKE cluster,

I have a deployment that request a GcePersistentVolume with a PVC, when it got created, I have a `Can’t scale up nodes` notification on my GCloud console.
If I inspect the log, it say that :

```
reason: {
messageId: "no.scale.up.mig.failing.predicate"
parameters: [
0: ""
1: "pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims"
```

Without creating this deployment, I have no Scale UP error at all.

The PVC in question :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  name: nfs
  namespace: nfs
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: standard
  volumeMode: Filesystem
status:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  phase: Bound
```

My deployment is running fine and the PV is directly created and bound to my PVC.

So I find this `Can't Scale up Nodes` really strange ?

(It's a single zone cluster, with a single NodePool).

Any idea for me ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52669115/8016720

Comment: It seem not really linked with my issue, in this link the problem is about HostLocal PV.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem. It is weird because if you are creating a PVC in GKE, the PV is created dynamically (and indeed it is), so you go and check with `kubectl get pv,pvc --all-namespaces` and everything seems normal. But it seems that when a deployment (that uses a PVC) is created and while waiting for the creation of the PVC this error appears and the cluster acknowledges it and displays the alert (creating some false positive alerts). It seems like a timing issue.

One turnaround is to change the value of the `storageClassName` definition. If instead of `standard` you use `standard-rwo` (both appear as default in Storage Classes tab in Storage) the problem seems to disappear. The consequence of this is that the type of the underlying disk changes from `Standard persistent disk` to `Balanced persistent disk`. Anyhow, the latter one performs better.

EDIT:
It is about Storage Classes. The volumeBindingMode of the default `standard` class is `Immediate`. According to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#volume-binding-mode):

> The Immediate mode indicates that volume binding and dynamic
> provisioning occurs once the PersistentVolumeClaim is created. For
> storage backends that are topology-constrained and not globally
> accessible from all Nodes in the cluster, PersistentVolumes will be
> bound or provisioned without knowledge of the Pod's scheduling
> requirements. This may result in unschedulable Pods.
>
> A cluster administrator can address this issue by specifying the
> WaitForFirstConsumer mode which will delay the binding and
> provisioning of a PersistentVolume until a Pod using the
> PersistentVolumeClaim is created. PersistentVolumes will be selected
> or provisioned conforming to the topology that is specified by the
> Pod's scheduling constraints. These include, but are not limited to,
> resource requirements, node selectors, pod affinity and anti-affinity,
> and taints and tolerations.

So, if all the properties of the `standard` `Storage class` are required to be kept, another solution would be to create another `Storage class`:

1. Download the YAML of the `standard` `Storage class`
2. Change the `name` definition
3. Change the property from `volumeBindingMode: Immediate` to `volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer`.
4. Apply it (`kubectl apply -f <file path>` )
5. And in the `storageClassName` definition of the PVC, change it to the name of the step #2